# discord.js modal giving error something went wrong

Tags: discord.js

Whenever i submit the modal it gives me error something went wrong try again..

this is my code -

```
const { Events, EmbedBuilder, AttachmentBuilder, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, InteractionType} = require('discord.js');
const { Verification } = require('../models/verificationSchema')
const { Captcha } = require('captcha-canvas')

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isButton()){
            if (interaction.customId === 'verify') {
                await interaction.deferReply({ephemeral: true});
                const member = await interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.user.id) || await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.member.user.id).catch(err => {});

                    const captcha = new Captcha();
                    captcha.async = true;
                    captcha.addDecoy();
                    captcha.drawTrace();
                    captcha.drawCaptcha();

                    const captchaAnswer = captcha.text;

                    const captchaImage = new AttachmentBuilder()
                    .setFile(await captcha.png)
                    .setName('captcha.png')
                
                    const captchaEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle('Verification Captcha')
                    .setColor('Yellow')
                    .setImage('attachment://captcha.png')
                    .setDescription(`Please enter the captcha text`)

                    const captchaRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
                    .addComponents([
                        new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setLabel('Answer')
                        .setCustomId('answer')
                        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                    ])

                    await interaction.editReply({embeds: [captchaEmbed], files: [captchaImage], components: [captchaRow]});

                }
            }
            if (interaction.customId === 'answer') {
                const modal = new ModalBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('verificationModal')
                    .setTitle('Verification Input')
                    .addComponents([
                        new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents([
                            new TextInputBuilder()
                            .setCustomId('captchaInput')
                            .setLabel("Enter the Captcha.")
                            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short),
                        ])
                    ]);
                interaction.showModal(modal);
            }
            if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
                console.log(interaction)
                if (interaction.customId === 'verificationModel') {
                  const response = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('captchaInput');
                    console.log(response)
                }
            }                                    
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a verification command in discord i ask the user for captcha text via the modal but it gives me error. i don't know how to fix this error i just want to get the user input in modal whenever the modal is submitted..

there is no error in the terminal.
thanks in advance :)
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKzTs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal is showing that because Discord expected a response to the modal interaction. If you don't want to send a message to the user when they submit the modal (e.g. by using `interaction.reply()`) then you can simply defer an update to the interaction using the [`ModalSubmitInteraction.deferUpdate()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ModalSubmitInteraction?scrollTo=deferUpdate) method. Example:

```js
if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
    interaction.deferUpdate()
    // all the other stuff you want to do with the modal submission here
}
```

What should happen here is that when the user clicks the submit button on your modal, Discord sends their submission to your bot, you respond that you simply want to defer the interaction, and then Discord closes the modal for the user without showing an error message.